# IOT vs Clustered Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, indexing

i work a lot with sql server but i am also interested in the oracle world. During college i learned SQL and database oriented stuff with oracle 8i.

In my current job i have to use sql server (meanwhile i am certified in sql server).

I remember the oracle times and i am beginning to wonder.

In sql server world everybody recommends clustered key tables i.e. a table organized as B-tree with data in leafs.

IIRC in oracle that would be an Index organized table (IOT). But why is it that everybody in the sql server world tells me clustered index is the default way to go (special cases omitted) and in the oracle world it seems to be standard to use a heap table and avoid IOT.

SO is there a difference between clustered index and IOT? Or why are there such different opinions of both.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the Oracle side but it's not without exceptions to the rule in SQL Server.

As a general guide when joining a table if you've added a sensible clustered index to it, the optimiser will see that it can access the pre-sorted data directly. ie it can home in on the records and pull them straight out.

Using a non clustered index you're more likely to be faced with bookmark lookups ie it identifies the indexed column values for a join but then has to look up the remaining columns in the table by their individual locations on disk to pull the data out - far less efficient. Covered indexes provide a workaround if well planned - meaning the columns you usually need are in the index itself, cutting out the need for a bookmark lookup.

Without either, looking at a heap for example, you're stuck with a scan. You're familiar with the use of binary trees in searches - it saves considerable I/O which grows with the size of the table.

Obviously each index to be maintained has an overhead when writing data, and in size. If you have a very small table or anything pinned, or small tables that frequently get emptied and reinserted there are exceptions where you may be better off without.

Hopefully that's not too brief but it's just for a general indication for you - not sure how that differs from Oracle though. Heading off now (early start) but message me if you want more information (just to remind me to nip back on this thread) unless the guys here can clarify in the meantime. New here but I'm only likely to post answers on those people have missed.

Comment: Well if you use non clustered indexes on heap tables you can lookup even faster beacuse in the leafnodes of the non clustered index (heap) you can find the rowid and in the leafnodes of an nonclustered index (clustered table) you find an id that you have to lookup in clustered tree again. That's the big problem i have.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How is a bookmark lookup faster (in any context) than a seek on an index. You have 3 key scenarios. 1) A heap. Much the same as a table scan scenario. You have to read every record to identify what you're after. 2) Next you have the clustered index seek. Using the statistics you can home in on the record very fast and get straight to reading it. 3) You have the lookup scenario ie from a non clustered index. Here you can identify the records you're after very quickly, but all that gives you is a series of non sequential addresses, which then have to be read.

Comment: Note if the tables small enough or dynamic enough an index seek may still come out comparably with a scan. For an example create 2 small tables one with a clustered index one with an unclustered index on a column you're going to search for. Now search for that column and return it. Next return all columns from the tables, but searching on your search column only.

Comment: With clustered you're likely to get a seek every time. Depending on your table size (data) with unclustered you'll get a seek operation when it's just that column returned, and either a table scan or bookmark lookup for the select * version (depending on data size etc)